# Simulate tableview row select from TableViewcell Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an app that checks to see whether a user has a particular file downloaded or not, and if they do not alert them with the chance to download it.  This code is called from within the UITableViewCell but I am not sure how to call the view controller with the tableView to simulate pressing the first row (the necessary file is always in the first row).

Here is a snippet of code

```
if (fileLbl.text == baseMapDisplayname) {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Basemap Not Downloaded", message: "Please first download the Offline Basemap", preferredStyle: .alert)

            var rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
            if let navigationController = rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
                rootViewController = navigationController.viewControllers.first
            }
            if let tabBarController = rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                rootViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController
            }

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel   ,handler: nil))
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Download", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                //TODO - Simulate action of selecting first row of tableview

               //this does not work
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                MainVC().tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
                MainVC().tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)

            }))
            rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

Comment: It seems to me you're creating new instances of MainVC, can't you use self ?
If you have the right controller instance selectRow should work, and also you don't need delegate, when self already is tableview delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a simple protocol that your `MainVC` conforms to, and it'll need to include a function to notify `MainVC` that the "Download" button was pressed.  Something like this:

```
protocol DownloadDelegate {
    func shouldDownloadFile()
}
```

So you'll need to set `MainVC` as the `DownloadDelegate` in the class that has that alert popping up by creating a variable like `var downloadDelegate: DownloadDelegate?`, and in the "Download" action you can say:

```
self.downloadDelegate?.shouldDownloadFile()
```

That will notify `MainVC`, and you can react by doing the `self.tableView.selectRow...` thing you already planned on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0);
self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

Comment: This does not work because tableView does not exist in the context of the UITableViewCell

Comment: This has nothing to do with the table cell, it's about notifying controller which owns the tableView of row selection. 
If you don' have a reference to MainVC instance, you could use delegate (protocol, suggested above), callback block (extending UIAlertController), notifications (NotificationCenter), presentingController from alertController etc